# Add an item from listview to favourite list

Tags: android

i'm looking for a good idea to make a fav list of a listview. the ListView is parsed from website server. I added new star image and once it clicked it change to yellow color as "favourited item", what i want is an idea of how to save this clicked item to a favourites list ... what i have think of yet is to make local xml file and add each item i click on to this xml and parse it in the favourites list activity, does it look as a good idea ? or there's a better way to do it ! thanks

Comment: I guess its easier to use an SQLite database.

Comment: so my idea is good, but i should use SQLite instead of xml ?

Comment: yes, no need to parse or generate XML and you can take advantage of the search facilities of the DB to look up a specific item.

Comment: post is as an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is good, but it is better to use an SQLite DB instead of an XML file. This will make the code easier as no XML parsing or generation is necesary and the data access to the DB is more flexible for instance if a specific item has to be fetched.